# Is there equivalent of git Revert/cherry-pick for Hg?

Tags: git, mercurial, git-revert

Is there a simple equivalent of using git revert, in mercurial? Apparently `hg revert` is mean to checkout a certain file, I haven't found a clear answer to how to add a commit (`git cherry-pick`) or apply the reverse diff of the commit (`git revert`).

I'm wanting to reverse some commits to default branch that were pushed out awhile back, not reversing those before or after - so hg backout, or hg revert don't seem to be the right command.

Answer (score 4):

The [Git-Hg Rosetta Stone](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Git-hg-rosetta-stone) is usually a good resource, but it doesn't handle the the cases you're looking for. As torek noted, http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Git_vs_Mercurial is another resource.

The equivalent of `git cherry-pick` is `hg graft`.

The equivalent of `git revert` is indeed `hg backout` - it appears you've misunderstood what it does in some way. `hg backout` will create a new changeset that reverses the changes in a single previous changeset. Since you're talking about a changeset from some time ago, `hg backout` will merge the changes into your working directory (do an `hg update -C` first) and you will have to manually commit it.

BTW `hg revert` will check out one or more files in the state they are in another changeset (by default, the changeset your working directory was last updated to). This includes the index state e.g. if the file is not tracked in your current changeset it will be reverted in the *added* state.

Answer (score 1):

Per http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Git_vs_Mercurial the equivalents are `hg graft` and `hg backout` respectively.

Why do you think backout is not the one you want?  It basically does a reverse-patch of an old commit (but does not autocommit in most cases).

Comment: Not that bad, although in one case it removes all of the original file, with new file, and gives an almost completely useless diff with <<< all of local ===== all of other >>>>